# Docu sign call back Ip range

Tags: docusignapi

What would be the range of **IP addresses**, we need to whitelist in order to successfully receive notification via callback?

Here is the callback url triggered from docusign, When the recipient sign the document. It is giving 403 error.

http://mysite.amazonaws.com/show-document-signed?signer=cmverify&envelopeId=ede11365-f57d-4c5c-bbe6-a4ccfcd5bebb&name=CM2%20CM2&event=signing_complete 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

The list of DocuSign IP addresses can be found [here.](https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature)

However, the 403 error that you show us in here, I'm not sure how did you determine it's an IP address issue. AWS typically doesn't require you to whitelist the IP addresses of incoming calls unless you specifically requested to restrict them. Not sure what is the URL above, but if it's your site, and in the log you do indeed see an error about IP address - then maybe that's the issue, but I'm not sure.